# New badge for the amount of visitors reached?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

With the new added statistic, the amount of people reached, isn't it time for a new badge for this statistic? For example,

- (bronze) 1k people reached
- (silver) 100k people reached
- (gold) 5m people reached

Of course, these values are just a little guess at the moment. I just picked some people with high reputation and checked their amount of people reached, and made up some numbers.

Comment: With greater values I agree.

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot Sure. The definitive numbers are of course not chosen by me. I made them something higher. Does it feels more accurate right now?

Comment: I'd say push the silver to 250K or even 500K.

Comment: but dont u think it will create more kind a advertising things? i mean everybody will try to sell them to gt the badge(specially lower levels)

Comment: Then it should already be a problem with the already existing tags for the view count of each individual questions (popular, notable, famous question). There are much more badges to be earned with that, instead of this proposal.

Comment: The problem here is that these badges need to work across *all Stack Exchange sites*. It'll be very hard to pick values that are reasonable goals for small sites, and not too damn easy for the busiest sites.

Comment: Meta.SE cross-site dupe: [Can we get some new badges based on the new "People Reached" stat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253509)

Comment: Hey, this is [my idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253509/can-we-get-some-new-badges-based-on-the-new-people-reached-stat)! Give it back! :)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I searched on this meta, not on the SE meta. I am terrible sorry for that. But it is a good idea :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, that's something that came up on MSE too. The bigger problem is that some of the *current* badges don't really scale to the smaller sites. I doubt it'll happen, but SE could possibly look into having certain badge requirements scale based on the user activity of the site, though I have no clue exactly how they would calculate something like that and keep it fair across *every* community.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen: and keep it fair across time. The view count badges are harder on small sites, but not impossible with a well-aimed social media post and a lot of luck. I don't think there are numbers that'll work across SE for the reached stat however, nor do I know what it'd promote.